# How to pass extra arguments to startapp command in bash?

Tags: django, django-commands

I want to pass values to `template_context` and the [docs says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#startapp):
`Any option passed to the startapp command (among the command’s supported options)`

What I understand is, that any extra argument that I pass, it will be set to the context dictionary. But I'm receiving the same error `(django-admin startapp: error: unrecognized arguments: --options=ok)`

```
django-admin startapp name_app --template="./templates" --options="ok"
```

I also tried with `-` and without it

```
django-admin startapp name_app --template="./templates" -a_value="ok"
```

and

```
django-admin startapp name_app --template="./templates" some_value="ok"
```

How am I supposed to add the extra arguments?
I know must be something easy, but I'm stuck for too much time now, and I couldn't find an example that uses it.

I'm using Django version 4.0.1

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: >>> django.__version__ === '4.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can pass something to template context within command

according to docs only template as I understand

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-startapp-template

Comment: Did you find the part that says: `Any option passed to the startapp command (among the command’s supported options)`